# ffmpeg zoompan filter zoom value limits

Tags: ffmpeg

Does ffmpeg [zoompan](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zoompan) filter has a cap for `z` value? I tried a simple test that stops zooming up at `10.5`. Is it that `10.5` is the maximum value for the `z` parameter or is there a limit for maximum frame dimensions?

zoompan=z='print(zoom + 0.5)'

Output:

```
2.000000
2.500000
3.000000
3.500000
4.000000
4.500000
5.000000
5.500000
6.000000
6.500000
7.000000
7.500000
8.000000
8.500000
9.000000
9.500000
10.000000
10.500000
Last message repeated 26 times
```

If there is such a limit its worth mentioning in the [docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zoompan) as well as the minimum of 1. That matters when choosing the tool to implement a certain effect.

I wish ffmpeg had some versatile capability of arbitrary zoom and positioning video input without limitations, like in any compositing software.

Comment: *worth mentioning in the docs* --> will appear in a few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zoom value is capped between `1` and `10`.

*I wish ffmpeg had some versatile capability of arbitrary zoom and positioninig video input without limitations*

Patch welcome.